# Can I make the locators in a locator pane move over the whole pane?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, locator

I'm trying use `LocatorPane` to produce locators that can move anywhere in the entire row of text I am displaying and not just in one of the rectangles, which is what happens in the code below.

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0.1, 0.95}, pt2 = {0.5, 0.95}}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}],
    Row[{
      "Brian O\[CloseCurlyQuote]Nolan\[CloseCurlyQuote]s The Third Policeman ", 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], White, Rectangle[{3, 1}, {0, 0}]}], 
      " begins and ends with the character of Sergeant Pluck ", 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], White, Rectangle[{3, 1}, {0, 0}]}], 
      " asks: \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Is it about a bicycle?\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote] \
was only published after \
O\[CloseCurlyQuote]Nolan\[CloseCurlyQuote]s death."
    }]
  ]
]
```

[image]

Using `GraphicsRow` allows the pane to move across the text, but this distorts the view of the text.

Does anyone have a better way of doing it? It has to be able to be cloud deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the lines of the following will work for you.

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {8, .5}, pt2 = {21, .5}},
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}],
    Graphics[
      {{FaceForm[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {35, 1}]},
       Inset[
         Row[
           {"Brian O\[CloseCurlyQuote]Nolan\[CloseCurlyQuote]s The Third Policeman ",
            Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], White, Rectangle[{3, 1}, {0, 0}]}],
            " begins and ends with the character of Sergeant Pluck ",
            Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], White, Rectangle[{3, 1}, {0, 0}]}],
           " asking: \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Is it about a bicycle?\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote] was only published after \
O\[CloseCurlyQuote]Nolan\[CloseCurlyQuote]s death."}]]},
      BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 13,
      ImageSize -> 1200]]]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer, I edited the question to highlight that I need it to deploy it on the cloud and with what you answered with it doesn't work.

Comment: @TimB. I don't use the Wolfram Cloud, so I know nothing about cloud deployment. Sorry, but I can't be of further help.

Comment: @TimB can you make this part of your question more apparent? Using something like a header formatting with markdown would make it stand out more. You might have better luck if you alter the wording of the actual question to include this.